# extract JSON data in Angular2

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have the following JSON output: http://pastebin.com/9bHaBrbX

I would like to make this pseudocode a reality:

```
For every Model {
     For every Year {
         For every Style {
           if submodel.body is NOT in Array:
              load submodel.body to Array;
         }
     }
}
```

I would like to store this Array in my model.component so I can use it to make buttons such as:

```
<button *ngFor="let item in Array" ...> item </button>
```

How can I extract the data I want (Model[x].Years[y].Style[z].submodel.body) (where x,y,z are variables) from my json response?

I am having trouble conceptualizing how to iterate through nested json objects with JS/TS/Angular2.

Comment: Sounds good. Do you have a question? See [ask].

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. If you want to `make it a reality` then you have to write some code... Try it yourself first, if you get stuck come back with your specific problem (and the details).

Comment: @igor, how do I extract this data from my json response?

Comment: JSON looks fine. Which exactly positions you want iterate through?

Comment: @Kinduser, I have edited my post. I guess I have trouble iterating through nested objects. Ideally I want to store the 'body' from the submodel object, which is nested in style, which is nested in year, which is nested in model.

Comment: Tip for your JSON. Make interfaces. Then just start untangling the nested stuff, start from the top level, and just "dig deeper", just like your pseudocode. Start iterating through Models, then years, then style... Start from the top level. Come back if you encounter an issue, THEN we can help :)

Comment: @AJT_82 I have interfaces (or models) in my models.ts class that handles this kind of output. However I am stuck with extracting this data with a javascript function (no ngFor yet) and removing duplicates --> then I would like this new (and unique) Array (or Object) to be available for my component template in which I can push the unique submodel bodies to a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint :

```
<div *ngFor="let years of model.years">
 <div *ngFor="let year of years">
  <div *ngFor="let styles of year.styles">
   <div *ngFor="let style of styles">
    <!-- your conditions, submodel.body... -->
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Side note: I agree with others above, you should try to write your code yourself.

Comment: instead of trying to display this data, I am trying to extract all the submodel.body values  with a function in my component which filters out duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Use simple `http` request, it will download the data and store it inside the `items` variable. Then you can do whatever you want with it - display, sort or just keep.

https://plnkr.co/edit/bU7W6f0aO6eelvyCnKzc?p=preview

Comment: I'm doing it this way:

`getModels(): void {
    this._EdmundsAPIService.getModels(this.route.snapshot.params[ 'data' ])
      .subscribe(
        models => this.models = models,
        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }`

but when I do 

`ngAfterContentInit() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.models.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.models[1]);
    }`

I get errors

Comment: Shouldn't be it `this.models[0]`? Anyways, use my method, it's actually the best way to do it.